# Openapi Generator: Disable enum Unmarshal JSON check for generated Go enum values

Tags: go, openapi-generator

Is it possible to disable the check for valid values in the generated model for enum values?

When I have an enum the following code is generated:

```golang
func (v *Status) UnmarshalJSON(src []byte) error {
    var value string
    err := json.Unmarshal(src, &value)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    enumTypeValue := Status(value)
    for _, existing := range AllowedStatusEnumValues {
        if existing == enumTypeValue {
            *v = enumTypeValue
            return nil
        }
    }

    return fmt.Errorf("%+v is not a valid Status", value)
}
```

I have my own validation logic though, therefore I do not want to throw an error here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The current solution is to use an older generator version like v7.0.1 which isn't generate the method